# ListView is not scrollable inside Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView inside a Column inside a Dialog. I only want the ListView to be scrollable, I have tried wrapping it inside an Expanded widget but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Below is the code snippet for the "Managers" column, I only want the ListView to be scrollable.

```
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Managers',
                          style: FontStyles.blackText16Bold,
                        ),
                        StatefulBuilder(
                          builder: (_, listState) {
                            return ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              children: List.generate(
                                allUsers.length,
                                (index) {
                                  return Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(allUsers[index]['name']),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          managersChanged = true;
                                          listState(() {
                                            managerCheckBoxes[index] = !managerCheckBoxes[index];
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon((managerCheckBoxes[index])
                                            ? Icons.check_box_rounded
                                            : Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded),
                                        color: (managerCheckBoxes[index]) ? MyColors.theme : Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: there's not enough space for the view to load.

Comment: yes, that's why I want the listview to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by wrapping a Expanded widget to all the rows and columns up the widget tree. The problem wasn't only the ListView itself, but all of it's parents as well.

```
                Expanded(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Managers',
                            style: FontStyles.blackText16Bold,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: StatefulBuilder(
                              builder: (_, listState) {
                                return ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: allUsers.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                    return Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(child: Text(allUsers[index]['name'])),
                                        IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            managersChanged = true;
                                            listState(() {
                                              managerCheckBoxes[index] = !managerCheckBoxes[index];
                                            });
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon((managerCheckBoxes[index])
                                              ? Icons.check_box_rounded
                                              : Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded),
                                          color: (managerCheckBoxes[index]) ? MyColors.theme : Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, left: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Employees',
                            style: FontStyles.blackText16Bold,
                          ),
                          StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (_, listState) {
                              return ListView(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                children: List.generate(
                                  filteredUsers.length,
                                  (index) {
                                    return Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(filteredUsers[index]['name']),
                                        IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            usersChanged = true;
                                            listState(() {
                                              checkBoxes[index] = !checkBoxes[index];
                                            });
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon((checkBoxes[index])
                                              ? Icons.check_box_rounded
                                              : Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded),
                                          color: (checkBoxes[index]) ? MyColors.theme : Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to try add `Expanded`

like

```
      Expanded(
        child: StatefulBuilder(
          ...
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this wasn't the full solution to my problem but I found the full solution after reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

insted of column use listview and give inner listview physics to neverScrollable. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this might Actually work in your case.**
I tried to add the widget in the **[SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)**.

```
    child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Managers',
      style: FontStyles.blackText16Bold,
    ),
    StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (_, listState) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: List.generate(
              allUsers.length,
              (index) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(allUsers[index]['name']),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        managersChanged = true;
                        listState(() {
                          managerCheckBoxes[index] = !managerCheckBoxes[index];
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon((managerCheckBoxes[index])
                          ? Icons.check_box_rounded
                          : Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded),
                      color: (managerCheckBoxes[index]) ? MyColors.theme : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```